# Unable to bypass password, /etc/sudoers not taking effect

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, sudo, password

I need to be able to run two bash scripts as sudo without having to provide the password.

One of these scripts is run on startup, it checks for inactivity, and if so, dims my laptop's backlit keys.

The other script is just something I use a lot, so its convenient to run it without password.

I had this working for a while, but during an update recently, my /etc/sudoers file was overwritten. I had my changed copy saved, but for some reason, the lines I put in there are no longer working, I'm being asked to provide the password.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. Here's my current /etc/sudoers file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# CUSTOM:       
ali ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/dim_keyboard.sh
ali ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/go

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

These lines:

```
ali ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/dim_keyboard.sh
ali ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/go
```

are what I've put in.

From looking at similar questions, I seem to be using the right syntax, but for some reason these lines still won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have `go` runnable as root without a password?! That is a *major* security hole!

Comment: _Not working_ means `sudo` is asking for password or what?

Comment: @KazWolfe It isn't the go language, its just a bash script I wrote. I didn't add .sh. :)

Comment: @heemayl Yes, sudo is asking for password

Comment: Ah. So, well, why is `go` in the sudoers file without a password?

Comment: @KazWolfe Because `go` is a bash script I wrote, it isn't the go language

Comment: Oh, I get you. Sorry for the confusion. Still haven't had my coffee.

Comment: Try `ali ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/go`

Comment: @heemayl does not work

Comment: That's expected as in absence of any username, `ALL` is assumed automatically but thought about giving a shot.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you running the command as user `ali`? and also can you show us how are you running the command exactly?

Comment: @heemayl yes, as user ali. Just from the terminal, e.g `sudo go` or `sudo /usr/local/bin/dim_keyboard`

Comment: Going right back to basics, in case something accidentally was left out: 1. Check that you have the path correctly specified, e.g. `ls /usr/local/bin/dim_keyboard.sh /usr/local/bin/go`. 2. Did you remember to change the sudoers file using `visudo`? 3. Did you issue `sudo -K` after changing the file?

Answer (score -1):

Why do we even need to use `sudo` for this application?

You can use a program such as [`shc`](https://github.com/neurobin/shc) to "compile" your shell scripts into a standalone executable binary, which you can just add to the `sudoers` file. Or, you can even set the [`setuid` bit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly) on it so it actually runs as root without needing `sudo`.

So, let's try an example:

```
shc -f myscript.sh -o myscript
sudo chown -R root:root myscript
sudo chmod a+x myscript
sudo chmod u+s myscript
```

This will take a shell script, and make it into a C executable that has `setuid` root. Whenever this is called (with or without `sudo`), it should always run (effectively) as the root user.

Comment: @heemayl Noted, and offending section removed.

Comment: Because I may need to make changes to the script and don't want to have to go thru the recompile process.

Comment: I've used this method, written a bash script to do the recompiling, and now things seem to be working. :) P.S shc doesn't take an `-o` flag, at least in the version I got by doing `apt-get install shc`. It instead creates two files, `script.sh.x` and `script.sh.x.c`. The `.c` is just the source code in C, I `rm -f` it. The `.x.` is the executable. I rename it to remove the `.x.`

Comment: No, this doesn't work anymore.

Inside the scripts, I need to take actions which require sudo permission. Even after I compile, if I try to execute the binary and run the above chmod / chown commands, i get asked to enter the password.

Putting the binaries inside `/etc/sudoers` also has no effect. So this problem is still unresolved. :(

Comment: @ClickUpvote Remove the `sudo` directives. Everything in the script is run effectively as root, so it's not needed.

Comment: They do not run as root, they run as the current user. I removed sudo  and just ran the binary, this was the output: `ali@beast:~$ dim_keyboard 1
tee: '/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness': Permission denied`

Comment: Running the same command as sudo worked.